# Continuation in a mainstream-ish programming language

Tags: programming-languages, computer-science

I need a mainstream language that supports continuations. Java never will (breaks `finally`), [Scala has deprecated it](https://github.com/scala/scala-continuations), ruby is silently [deprecating it as well](http://www.atdot.net/~ko1/pub/ContinuationFest-ruby.pdf)...

Does any other mainstream, non FP-only language support them and does not plan to deprecate it? I actually need the ability to jump back in the code°.

° that's for a PhD thesis, not a production app :-).

Comment: What about Scheme, the originator of CALL/CC?

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion - it won't do. I need a programming language that at least looks procedural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python looks procedural, supports functional programming and has continuation implemented here:
http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stackless.html#continulets

Also check out asyncio tulip:
https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio.html

Comment: Thanks! Almost what I needed, as I need to run the continuations multiple times (backtracking on possible interleaving of a multithreaded execution).